# Connecting Calendar to Another Application

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, javascript, calendar, 2019

Using SharePoint 2013 and SharePoint 2019 is there a way to connect a calendar to HR application that collects dates of events and important notices. Here is the scenario.  I want to pull the dates from the HR application of events and put them in a SharePoint calendar. Is there a way to do this? I was thinking of using a Page Viewer web part.  Thank you for any help.

Comment: What are the available data formats that your HR application can output?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to sync the events date of HR application with outlook calendar. Then sync outlook calendar with SharePoint calendar.